# how to completely hide the url in yii2

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, yii2

Using yii2, i am creating a page to display the results of a category, and stuck in url rules.

Now, i have a category whose name is like `training-centers` and the id of this category is `5`
and need to pass this categoryid to education controller with list action.

I need to write a rule of this in yii2,

```
'training-centers' => 'education/list' //how to pass the id
```

How to write this type of rule where id or other identifier is not avaialble in url?

Can/How we do it using .htacess?

After enabling the pretty url, it doesnt work with

```
RewriteRule training-centers index.php?r=education-list&id=5
```

In one line, how can we write the url in yii where controller/action/id are not identifiable in url?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'rules' => [         
        'training-centers' => 'index.php?r=education-list&id=5'
     ]
 ],
```

Or in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^training-centers$ /education/list/?id=5
```